# Translating "may turn into this"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, sentence-translation

I need some help to translate a phrase:

> ***That which was fabric/woven, may turn/become/transform into this***

My partner gave me some time ago, a handmade bracelet made from fabric, symbolising our sentiments for each other.

I'm planning to gift her a gold bracelet and I wanted to engrave this phrase.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For "turn into" (as in "transform"), I would use *mūtāre in* with accusative, as in the very beginning of Ovid's *Metamorphoses*:

> In nova fert animus mutatas dicere formas / corpora;
> *I intend to talk about people transformed into new shapes;*

In Latin, words like "that which was woven" and "this" need a gender. Normally I'd use the gender of the word for "bracelet", but no obvious word for that comes to mind, so I'm defaulting to neuter.

With those choices made, the rest of the translation is straightforward:

> In hoc textum mūtet.
> *A woven thing may turn into this thing.*

(For most purposes, you'd want to write the last word as *mutet*, without the mark over the U; it represents a pronunciation distinction that vanished in later Latin.)